# Handlebars: native inline conditional expression or equivalent?

Tags: if-statement, expression, inline, conditional-statements, handlebars.js

How can I have an inline conditional expression in a Handlebars template?

There is a way to do that within a "native" way? I mean, without registering a custom helper?

For example, I've been playing with the code (with the parenthesis and without them):

```
<select name="alignment">
     <option value="left" {{ #if (options.text_alignment == 'left') }}selected="selected"{{ /if }}>Left</option>
     <option value="center" {{ #if (options.text_alignment == 'center') }}selected="selected"{{ /if }}>Center</option>
     <option value="right" {{ #if (options.text_alignment == 'right') }}selected="selected"{{ /if }}>Right</option>
</select>
```

but it doesn't work at all and throws the error:

```
Error: Parse error on line 20:
 ...ion value="left" {{ #if (options.text_al
 -----------------------^
 Expecting 'ID', 'DATA', got 'INVALID'
    [Break On This Error] 

throw new Error(str);
```

So, how I can have an inline conditional statement in the form of `if/else` structures or the classic ternary operator `(var == value)?'yes':'no'`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally, I was able to accomplish that but I've to say it, in a not nice way :(

I registered a custom helper like the following:

```js
    // Need to mark selected option inside a select.
    Handlebars.registerHelper('select', function(variable, value) {
        if (variable == value) {
            return new Handlebars.SafeString('selected=selected');
        }
        else {
            return '';
        }
    });
```

This custom helper can be used like that:

```
    {{select option 'right'}}
```

where `option` is the variable to be tested and `'right'` the value against it is tested.

If later anyone come with a nice solution that works also for `radios` & `checkboxes` please, add the answer that I will be happy to vote up them :D

Answer (score 3):

## [inline if statement](https://guides.emberjs.com/v1.11.0/templates/conditionals/#toc_inline-if-syntax):

```js
<div class="message {{if isImportant 'important' 'unimportant'}}"></div>
```

Comment: It seems like ember-only addition

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is the only way you can do it without registering a custom helper.

[Handlebars.js Else If](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10736907/handlebars-js-else-if)

Comment: Can you post a sample like mine with a select and options to be selected depending on the variable options? The above code I posted doesn't work for me. Thanks.