# Handlebars custom if equals helper not compiling

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I've added a custom helper in Handlebars to accomplish an `if == "some string"` type helper. The helper code is this:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('if_eq', function(a, b, opts) {
    if(a == b) // Or === depending on your needs
        return opts.fn(this);
    else
        return opts.inverse(this);
});
```

The template is this:

```
<div id="appStoreParametersModal" class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content appStoreParametersModal">
        <div class="modal-header hypersignModalHeader">
            <h3>{{appName}}</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div id="app-params">
                {{#each appParm}}
                <form>
                    {{#if_eq uiControlType "text"}}
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="{{qsName}}">{{uiName}}</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="{{qsName}}" placeholder="{{uiName}}"/>
                    </div>
                    {{else if_eq uiControlType "dropdown"}}
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="{{qsName}}">{{uiName}}</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="{{qsName}}">
                            {{#each defaultVals}}
                                <option value="{{value}}">{{displayName}}</option>
                            {{/each}}
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    {{/if_eq}}
                </form>
                {{/each}}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning cancel" data-dismiss="modal" id="cancel">Cancel</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="appStoreNext">Next</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm getting this error:

> Uncaught Error: if_eq doesn't match each

It seems to be a problem with using the `{{else}}`, because if I only use the `if_eq` helper without an `else`, then it works fine. I'm pretty new to Handlebars, so I'm sure I'm missing something stupid.

Comment: This would suggest using {{else}} {{#if...}}, because there is no else if. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10736907/handlebars-js-else-if

Comment: It's working for me... http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pJYEpQ

Comment: Well, that's odd. I wonder why it doesn't work for me. Maybe it's related to the version of Handlebars. The app I'm working on is using jquery-handlerbars 1.0.0, so that probably has a very outdated version of handlebars in it.

Comment: Yeah, looks like that is it. They added the syntax for else if in version 3 and we are super far behind. Doing the nested {{else}} with an {{#if_eq}} inside of it seems to have solved it.

Answer (score 14):

`if_eq doesn't match if` is thrown when you have `{{#if_eq stuff "stuff"}}` but you end it by mistake in `{{/if}}` instead of `{{/if_eq}}`.