# if else in handle bar template

Tags: handlebars.js, handlebarshelper

```
In need to check this scenario using handle bar templates
if(data.Id==1 && Isreal==false)
{
//`enter code here
}
else if(data.id==2 && IsReal==true)
//other html
else
`//enter code here`last html
```

How can I do that, I tried using helper but it is not working in my case

Comment: possible duplicate of [Handlebars.js Else If](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10736907/handlebars-js-else-if)

Comment: Can I compare values in template html?

Comment: {{#if Status==1}}
  ///Some Html
{{#else}}
{{#if status==2}}
//Some html
{{#if}}
{{#if}}

This is my scenario I need to compare values..Is this possible in this

Please help

Comment: `{{#if Status==1}}
  ...
{{else}} {{#if status==2}}
  ...
{{else}}
  ...
{{/if}}{{/if}}`

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is to not do any business logic in the template but instead do it before and pass it through the context into the template.

i.e.

```
var context = {
    dataOneNotReal = data.Id==1 && Isreal==false,
    dataTwoIsReal = data.id==2 && IsReal==true
};
```

then in the template

```
{{#if dataOneNotReal}}
    // code
{{else}}
    {{#if dataTwoIsReal}}
        // code
    {{else}}
        // code
    {{/if}}
{{/if}}
```