# Logical OR/AND Handlebars.JS Helper, Multiple Arguments, First One Always Being Checked

Tags: jquery, handlebars.js, handlebarshelper

The following was proposed as a logical AND/OR multi-arg Handlebars.JS helper:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper({
    and: function () {
        return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).every(Boolean);
    },
    or: function () {
        return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).some(Boolean);
    }
});
```

[Handlebars.js Else If](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10736907/handlebars-js-else-if)

This doesn't work for me because I need to call it as

```
{{#if (or questionType 'STARTTIME' 'ENDTIME') }}

{{#if (or questionType 'STARTTIME' 'ENDTIME' 'ARGUMENT3' 'ARGUMENT4') }}
```

In other words,

1. I support multiple args for my AND/OR,
2. T**he first arg is always what I'm checking**, e.g.

   *return (questionType == arg1 || questionType == arg2 || questionType == arg3 ...)*

In other words, I can't write a dumb 2-param or(..) / and(..) like this,

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('or', function(a, b, c) {
    if(a == b || a == c)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
});
```

It should be multi-argument, with the first one always being checked. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: Your original `or` helper is not going to work. Handlebars passes an additional meta object as the final argument when invoking a helper. For example, using your `or` helper in a template as `(or false false)` results in the helper function being executed with the following `arguments` object:

```
{
    0: false,
    1: false,
    2: {
        "name": "or",
        "hash": {...},
        "data": {...}
    },
    length: 3
}
```

The existence of that Object at `3` will evaluate to `true` in the `Boolean` conversion and cause your helper to return `true` despite that the call site passes only `false` values.

To make the helper work as intended, we need to exclude the last arg when [slicing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) our `arguments` object. (FYI: The purpose of the `slice` is to convert the array-like `arguments` Object to an Array, so that we may call Array.prototype methods on it, like `.some`.) To do this, we update our `or` helper to be:

```
return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0, -1).some(Boolean);
```

Now we can turn to the problem of comparing our first argument expression to the rest. We can similarly update our `.slice` call to exclude the first argument as well: `.slice.call(arguments, 1, -1)`. Then we need only to compare each item in the slice to the first argument. Our helper becomes:

```
return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1, -1).some(arg => arg === arguments[0]);
```

Our helper now works as we intend; but I would urge you to rename it as it not an "or" operation, but an "in".

Comment: You're exactly right on all points. That suggested answer had a bug which took me an hour debug, the missing -1 exclusion for the last arg which is the meta object. Thanks for the solution.